# .net where to start

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .net project and I am not a .net developer but I want to learn as I go through the process. I have been given a folder with some C# files and folders like bin etc.  I heard that the project was developed in .net 2005. I try to open it in .net 2010 and it asks me to convert it. I converted it but I am not sure what to do next. The syntax doesnt have any colors or anything. Any help will be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Which company do you work for?? :-) . You are given a project to learn? What is your experience in other programming languages? Are you the only team member?

Comment: How can you write code without *syntax highlighting*? Oh, the horror!

Comment: @Shoban one that doesn't want to spare the expense of hiring a .NET developer.

Comment: @Greg Whatever did we do before syntax highlighting?!? =)

Comment: Man, the harshness.. This IS a real question. All of us started somewhere.

Comment: Do u have any background in programming?

Comment: The best way to learn is to do something fun.

Find something cool you want to do. For example I bought myself a [Kinect](http://blog.tedd.no/index.php/2011/02/01/early-alpha-release-kinect-c-starter-kit/) a few weeks back. Great fun!

When you are having fun you will be motivated to push yourself through problem after problem. As a developer this is a skill you will need to aquire. The road will be filled with difficult obstacles for as long as you develop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/default.aspx

There are so many resources out there to learn a huge amount of information, but this site was created specifically for beginning .NET developers, and it is done well.

My boy was able to start developing at 8 years old with little help from me, by going to the Kids section, so it's a nice gentle introduction.

Answer (score 2):

Try [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). That is the msdn links for the basic tutorials for beginners. Also the documentation in MSDN is really complete for reference and also in case you need to clarify concepts you don't understand.

Comment: I had been to tutorials and thats why I asked here after getting all confused! :)

Comment: Are you having troubles completing the tutorials in that site? Have you got any specific question? Perhaps on how to get setup for your very first project? You can always download the source files for better understanding of the overall process.